# MS VS 2015 Debugging c# website on Windows Server 2003 with iis 6.0 possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I have a website project written in c# using VS 2015 and when testing locally the website works with no hiccups but when the website is published on a server it has an error. What can be te problem. Because overall it worked fine and i have not changed anything critical just some typos but now it is not working.

dev machine is a windows 10 with latest .net and VS2015
server is windows 2003 with .net 4.0 and iis 6.0

Is it possible to remote debug this website?

Comment: It's possible, but remote debugging a site is almost never needed and is often a sign that you have very poor logging and/or insight into how your site is running.

Comment: I admit that logging is not the websites strong suit. Should i implement Nlog? Or you would suggest something else?

Comment: What is the error that is now showing? Is there any error message or exception details that you could add to your question?

Comment: My bet is on the server (Windows 2003 {no longer supported by MS}) try publishing to Azure see if you get any issue ...